# Hide text underneath the image/background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sticky

I have my logo (an image inside a div) with these properties in `jade`-

`style="opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);display:block;border-bottom: thick solid #000000;background:rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)"`

This div is on the page top and a report displayed as the main content. I am using `stickyjs` to keep the logo fixed on scrolling down the page.
But, when i scroll down, the page content behind the logo is not hidden and is visible as text behind the image as,

[image]

How can i set options for `background-color`, to hide the text contents lying underneath?

Comment: put your logo inside a div and make the div sticky instead of the logo, last set a background color to the div

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the point of the word "background" in the style's name?

Comment: no change, Juan... i put my logo inside `div(id="sticker", style="background-color:transparent;background:rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)" )`. Still, the text is visible.

Comment: Is there a reason the background color is transparent? Could you make it the same as your body background color?

Comment: i removed `background-color` style since the default value is `transparent` and so it is redundant here.

Comment: Would you mind throwing it into a JSFiddle or CodePen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, without knowing your site architecture, here's a sample of what you could do...

**[Working CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/aOJoGp)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="header">
    <img src="http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-1c93adf1d2e3c02dcb629a40fb065e81.png" />
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>This is the body content.</p>
    ...
    <p>
    <p>This is the body content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;  /* Keeps the header fixed at the top of the page */
  top:0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #fff;   /* opaque background to hide text */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#header img {
  height: 100%;
}
#content {
  position: absolute;   /* begin content beneath header */
  top: 55px;
  z-index: -1;          /* hide the body text */
}
```

You don't need JS to fix a header at the top of the page. I'd suggest simplifying and using CSS positioning to make sure the header bar stays at the top of the page.